# SugarCRM - Correctly display total number of entries in Dashlet

Tags: sugarcrm

I am looking for a way, to correctly display the total number of entries in a SugarCRM dashlet. Right now, it is display as "(1 - 5 of 6+)", with 6+ being everything >= 6. I want the absolute number.

Thank you,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your config_override.php file...

```
$sugar_config['disable_count_query'] = false;
```

Or simply remove the existing $sugar_config['disable_count_query'] setting in either config_override.php or config.php